# Selenium IDE and PHP unit. How to perform single testcase with multiple roles? by implementing user credentials

Tags: eclipse, phpunit, selenium-ide

Greeting I started to create testcases for my webpage, and in some cases I have created scenario where testcase needs to be perfomed as multiple roles.

- One testcase
- one scenario
- multiple roles (to enter with different user credentials)

I was thinking to create each test case for every role, but that takes time if there is many test cases to be done. So there should be an possibility to create one test case and later on when exported as PHP (PHPUnit) script I just need to **log in with different user credentials.**

For example:

**- 1 Script
 - 3 roles (user A,user B,user C)
 - performed test case for all three of them**

Is this possible what I'm talking about.
Maybe to call credentials from some mySQL database and connecting all this with Eclipse?

Any idea somebody?

ps. I couldnt find single word about this by googleing

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use [data providers](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) for it.

```
class LoginTest extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     */
    public function testLogin($login, $password)
    {
    $this->url('/login');
    $this->byId('login')->value($login);
    $this->byId('password')->value($password);
    $this->byId('submit')->click();
    }

    public function provider()
    {
        return array(
          array('User a', 'Password a'),
          array('User b', 'Password b'),
          array('User c', 'Password c'),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: IF for example my test cases contains this script: